# Can't curl to the site from inside the server where it is hosted and it returns 403 Forbidden, but using curl from outside to the site is fine

Tags: curl, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have this site, I'm trying to use curl

> curl -ikL http://example.no/

from inside the server where it is hosted,
and it gives me this,

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>       Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 06:27:08 GMT
>       Server: Apache/2.4.25
>       Content-Length: 209
>       Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
> <html><head>
> <title>403 Forbidden</title>
> </head><body>
> <h1>Forbidden</h1>
> <p>You don't have permission to access /
> on this server.<br />
> </p>
> </body></html>
> ```

but when I try to use curl using different PC, I'm getting the right output

[image: curl result from outside]

I have no problem accessing it from the browser

[image: browser result from outside]

here is the site's Apache config

```
ServerName ${DOM}
ServerAlias www.${DOM}
ServerAlias mail.${DOM}
DocumentRoot ${HOME}/app/public
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/${DOM}_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/${DOM}_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ ${HOME}/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory ${HOME}/app/public>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory ${HOME}/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

I'm using virtualmin, this has subdomain, which is fine, I can curl page of its subdomain from inside the server.

Comment: can you try curl with http://example.no/index.html or http://example.no/index.php ?

Comment: @abestrad : i can curl its subdomain

Comment: @SanthoshKumar : Yes, still 403 Forbidden

Comment: does it perhaps use different IP addresses for that name on the inside vs the outside?

Comment: @DanielStenberg only 1 ip